# Problem in detecting bluetooth headset media button event by overriding onKeyDown() method in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, keyevent

I am trying to build an application that records audio which is then sent to a Speech-to-Text API to receive its transcription.

I want that the application is able to interact with a Bluetooth headset/headphone on which I can press a button (play/pause button) to start that recording and press again to end the recording.

I am using **react-native-keyevent** library to handle the keyEvent. It is working fine with the wiered haedsets but I am not able to capture the events by the play/pause button on my bluetooth headset.

```
componentDidMount(){
   KeyEvent.onKeyDownListener((keyEvent) => {
     console.log(`onKeyDown keyCode: ${keyEvent.keyCode}`);
     //My Event handler here.
   });
}
```

Manifest.XML

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
  </application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override 
      public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        KeyEventModule.getInstance().onKeyDownEvent(keyCode, event);
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        return true;
      }
```